# How to correctly add data from socket to react state array

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm making a simple socket.io chat app. Every time a user joins the chat I want a message that states they joined. Currently it works correctly the first time, but if a user leaves and joins again or another user joins the message appears multiple times.

```js
// Backend (express)
// server.js
const socketIO = require ('socket.io');

const expressServer = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
const io = socketIO(expressServer);

// setting socketio to access from auth route.
app.set('socketio', io);

// auth route
// login.js
var io = req.app.get('socketio');
// login even ...
io.emit('login', {username: user.username, time: time, action: 'Joined!'})
```

```js
// Frontend (react)
// chat.js
const [usersLoggedIn, setusersLoggedIn] = useState([])
socket.on('login', function (res) {
  console.log('res:', res)
  setusersLoggedIn(state => [res, ...state])
});

// Added for context - how I show the messages:
// An activity log showing that users have signed into the chat and at what time.
usersLoggedIn.map((user, index) => (
    <div>
       <div>{moment(user.time).fromNow(true)}</div>
       <div>@{user.username}</div>
       <div>{user.action}</div>
    </div>
))
```

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1xPm.png)
shows first user 'test' joined once after logging in & shows second user 'other' joined twice after logging in. I don't think I'm handling it in the best way, but I'm not sure of another way or why it's returning it multiple times. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you do not remove any user from the array. How do you show the messages using `usersLoggedIn`?

Comment: updated my answer @AhmetEmreKılınç, I'm just logging it currently in a sidebar and not inside the chat itself. I want the data to persist so I'm not removing it yet.

Comment: It is reasonable to see the same message multiple times if logout event is not handled since on every login event you add the same user to the array. But according to this code, I cannot see any reason why multiple messages are shown when another user is logged in for the first time.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç That's what makes me believe that it shouldn't matter. I want it to act somewhat like an activity log basically alerting user activity, so I don't want the action of "Joined" to be removed from the state. I'll add more details to see if there's something I'm overlooking...